# Как засунуть значение в select с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Имеется такой код:
**delivery.blade.php**

```
<select class="selectpicker filter delivery-select" data-width="375" id="regionForDelivery">
                    @foreach($regions as $region)
                    <option id="{{ $region->biznes_region }}2" value="{{ $region->biznes_region }}">{{ $region->biznes_region }}</option>
                    @endforeach
</select>

<select class="form-select" multiple id=selectedRegion>
                           
                                <option></option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>

<script src="/js/delivery.js"></script>
```

**delivery.js**

```
$('#regionForDelivery').change(function (){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/delivery',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            region: 'hi',
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#just').html(data);
            console.log('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

Как с помощью ajax сделать так, чтобы выбранный город добавлялся в option внутрь select-а, id которого равен selectedRegion?

Answer (score 0):

После этой строки:

```
console.log('success');`
```

вставьте:

```
document.getElementById("selectedRegion").innerHTML += "<option>" + data.response + "</option>";
```

Comment: Спасибо большое